# Is is possible to requireSession and request permission publish_stream in f8 connect at once?

Tags: facebook

I'm integrating my site with Facebook Connect.

I wonder if it's possible to request permission **publish_stream** at the same time that user is logging first time to the site using Facebook Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by all at once, but yea sorta. Connecting with facebook, logging in, authorizing, and allowing the publish stream permission will all be in the same flow in the same modal that pops up.

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream", function(result){
    //post auth callback
});
```

This will prompt the user to log in as well as authorize the app and prompt for extended permissions. I believe the callback function is only called when the user authorized the extended permissions.